# Where does the duality comes from in linear programing and can we get the optimal basis from it?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

$$\begin{cases}
\max & c^Tx\\
& Ax\le b\\
& x\ge 0
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\min & y^Tb\\
& y^TA\ge c^T\\
& y^T\ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Then we come to the following formula

$$c^Tx\le y^TAx\le y^Tb$$

**I don't know where this comes from.** It allows to have:

$$c^Tx\le y^TAx\le \tilde y^TAx \le \alpha$$

It seems to be linked to dual linear program resolution which leads to:

$$y^T\ge x^TAy\ge \tilde x^TAy\alpha$$

From this we can obtain the value $\alpha$ of the optimum, still, **can we have the optimal basis?**

Answer (score 1):

Well,

$$Ax \le b$$

Now pre-multiply $y^T$ on both sides.

Also,

$$c^T \le y^T A$$

Now post-multiply $x$ on both sides.